# is there any solution to split this data on numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any solution how to split this data, data was aquired with this code:

```
 frame = cv2.resize(img,(224,224))
        image_array=np.asarray(frame)
        normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1
        TM_DATA[0]=normalized_image_array
        PredictionVariable = model.predict(TM_DATA)
        arr = np.array(PredictionVariable)
```

The resulst are:

```
     [[0.98117685 0.01882314]]
     [[0.9549644  0.04503556]]
     [[0.9622084  0.03779164]]
     [[0.9471438  0.05285629]]
     [[0.98117685 0.01882314]]
```

Assuming if this data was pulled with numpy, I was using these commands to split:

```
np.array_split
np.hsplit
np.vsplit
np.dsplit
```

When I've tried to split data, i was using this:

```
split = np.array_split(arr, 2)
```

And results were:

```
[array([[0.98117685, 0.01882314]], dtype=float32), array([], shape=(0, 2), dtype=float32)]
```

The wanted results should look like this:

```
X=0.98117685, Y=0.01882314
```

I'm using tensorflow.keras,numpy and opencv

Comment: Are you looking for a X and Y vector or what?

Comment: i'm looking just values nothing else

Comment: Maybe it's a silly question: have you considered slicing?

Comment: sadly, no effects

Comment: rpanani thank you for the tip

Comment: I'm removing tensorflow tag

Comment: is my answer useful for you?

Comment: yes, your answer is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you just need to select the given elements. first row, first column and first row, second column

```py
import numpy as np
m = np.array(
    [[0.98117685, 0.01882314],
     [0.9549644,  0.04503556],
     [0.9622084,  0.03779164],
     [0.9471438,  0.05285629],
     [0.98117685, 0.01882314]])

X = m[0, 0]
Y = m[0, 1]
```